# How to open a file path with another app in kivy on android?

Tags: python, android, file, kivy

I retrieved the path of a file by os module in this format: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20220702_140610_154.jpg".

How do I implement to open the popup at the bottom of the app and choose to open it with gallery app or send in WhatsApp or other messengers?